# Can I bind a service after unbind in Android?

Tags: android, service

First, Here is my code.

```
Class<?> ContextImplClass = Class.forName("android.app.ContextImpl");

// private final LoadedApk mPackageInfo
Field mPackageInfoField = ContextImplClass.getDeclaredField("mPackageInfo");
mPackageInfoField.setAccessible(true);

Object mPackageInfo = mPackageInfoField.get(currentActivity.getBaseContext());

Class loadedApkClass = mPackageInfoField.getType();
Field mServicesField = loadedApkClass.getDeclaredField("mServices");
mServicesField.setAccessible(true);

// Object -> LoadedApk.ServiceDispatcher
ArrayMap<Context, ArrayMap<ServiceConnection, Object>> mServices = null;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
  mServices = (ArrayMap<Context, ArrayMap<ServiceConnection, Object>>)
              mServicesField.get(mPackageInfo);
}

if (mServices == null)
  return;

for (Context context : mServices.keySet()) {
  for (ServiceConnection conn : mServices.get(context).keySet()) {
    // Maybe JNIBridge
    if (conn.toString().contains("<native proxy object>")) {
      currentActivity.unbindService(conn);

      // Can't not start
      boolean wasStart = currentActivity.bindService(getIntent(), conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know the `ServiceConnectionImpl`.
I guess the `JNIBridge`.
Because I can find a name where `Proxy.cpp` in `JNIBridge`.

```
conn.toString()): < native proxy object \>  
conn.getClass().getSimpleName().trim()) -> $Proxy0
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: @pskink I want to replace MyServiceConnection or just rebind If I want at point.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I had to bind service when already running in background when the application was started again. I used this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isMyServiceRunning(AudioPlayerService.class)) {
        bindService(new Intent(this, AudioPlayerService.class),
                this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if(manager != null) {
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm checking that the service is still running and bind it to activity. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: The service was started by maybe os. So I can't use your code. Because I don't know Service whan call bindService()..